# Not able to return out of recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I have the following piece of code. It aims at traversing the [attached screenshot] Tree structure in depth first manner.[image]

As you can see, I am interested in the highlighted entry in green -> **Has Class( DatasetType )** node of this tree structure. This Tree structure is subjected to additions of new nodes by customers. So, I have to traverse the Tree structure to find my node of interest. I have formulated the below code. But And I can see that it identifies that node of my interest.

However, it is not stopping there. It is proceeding onto the next sibling i.e., Has Class( EPMJob ). I want my processing to stop. I am pretty sure that my way of returning stuff is missing something. but not able to pin point.

Any inputs are most welcome.

```
tag_t findHasTypeDatasetNodeInAMTree( tag_t amTreeNode )
{
    CharPointer nodeName;
    Response stat = askRuleName( amTreeNode, &nodeName );

    CharPointer nodeArgument;
    stat = askRuleArg( amTreeNode, &nodeArgument );

    if( tc_strcmp( nodeName.getString(), "Has Class" ) == 0 && tc_strcmp( nodeArgument.getString(), "DatasetType" ) == 0 )
    {
        return amTreeNode;
    }

    int numChildNodes = 0;
    TagPointer childNodes;
    stat = askChildren( amTreeNode, &numChildNodes, &childNodes );

    if( numChildNodes == 0 )
    {
        return NULLTAG;
    }

    // The following is the piece that needs attention. 
    // Do not want to NULL check here though
    for( int inx = 0; inx < numChildNodes; ++inx )
    {
        findHasTypeDatasetNodeInAMTree( childNodes[inx] );
    }

    return NULLTAG;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what this is doing:

```
for( int inx = 0; inx < numChildNodes; ++inx )
{
    findHasTypeDatasetNodeInAMTree( childNodes[inx] );
}
```

But I'm pretty sure it doesn't stop when you find something so the result is ALWAYS `NULLTAG`. How about something like:

```
for( int inx = 0; inx < numChildNodes; ++inx )
{
    auto result = findHasTypeDatasetNodeInAMTree( childNodes[inx] );
    if( result != NULLTAG )
        return result;
}
```